# Can I depend on all the Bazel targets matching a pattern, without listing them individually?

Tags: bazel

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
some-root/
└── my-stuff/
    ├── BUILD
    ├── foo/
    │   └── BUILD
    ├── bar/
    │   └── BUILD
    └── baz/
        └── BUILD
```

I'd like to have a target like `//some-root/my-stuff:update` which runs all of `//some-root/my-stuff/foo:update`, `//some-root/my-stuff/bar:update`, `//some-root/my-stuff/baz:update`.

I can do this by listing each target as a dependency. However, if I have many of these and I want to be able to add more it becomes a pain (it's easy to add a bunch of subdirectories and miss adding one to the parent `BUILD` file).

Is there a way to do a wildcard labels or otherwise discover labels from file paths? I'm able to do `bazel test //some-root/my-stuff/...` to run all tests under a path, but I can't seem to use that pattern inside of a `BUILD` file and what I'd want is more like `bazel run //some-root/my-stuff/...:update` which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all labels with the name `update` from the command line:

```
bazel query "attr(name, '^update$', //...)"
```

and take the output of query and manually edit your dependencies.

But unfortunately you can not put this into a [`genquery rule`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genquery) (which would generate the list of targets to depend on), because

> queries containing wildcard target specifications (e.g. //pkg:* or //pkg:all) are not allowed